# WPF - TextBlock Question

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBlock control defined as follows:

```
<TextBlock Width="250"
           Height="23"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="20,16,0,0"
           Name="RecipeName"
           Text="{Binding Recipe.RecipeName}"/>
```

Instead of hard-coding a width of 250, I would like the TextBlock to calculate the width it needs to display the whole text. I assume there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It normally should fit to content automatically if the `Width` is not set. To get this automatic width use the `ActualWidth` property.

To explicitly tell the control to auto-size use

```
Width="Auto"
```

The actual sizing behavior is also dependent on the `HorizontalAlignment` property, if it is set to `Stretch` the control will *not* fit to content but to container.

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx).

---

**Edit:** Some visualisation:

```
<TextBlock Text="SetLeft"     Width="200"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="SetCenter"   Width="200"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="SetStretch"  Width="200"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="AutoLeft"    Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="AutoCenter"  Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="AutoStretch" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="OmitLeft"                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"     Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="OmitCenter"               HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Background="Yellow"/>
<TextBlock Text="OmitStretch"              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="Yellow"/>
```

[image]

Comment: @H.B. - Nice summary, but need to mention the parent element. For example, if the TextBlock is in a Grid column with a fixed width, then TextBlock could still appear clipped.

Comment: Do you mean that the width could become smaller than the optimal width because the container is too small?

Comment: @H.B. - No, that would only happen if using stretch. But if the container's width is 50, the TextBlock's desired with is 100, then the TextBlock will get clipped.

Comment: That behaviour seems a bit trivial to me.

Comment: @H.B. - The layout of the TextBlock is entirely determined by it's parent. If you wrap your example above in a DockPanel, then you get entirely different results. But you're right that it probably doesn't apply to this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the Width setting, then it's size is dependent on it's parent. If you post the surrounding XAML, that would help to determine the sizing behavior.